# When I change SConstruct file, scons doesn't trigger rebuild?

Tags: linux, triggers, scons, rebuild

First, I've got SConstruct file like this:

```
Object('a.s')
Program('mya','a.o')
```

I run scons, it generates 'mya'. OK. Then I change my SConstruct to be:

```
Object('a.s',CCFLAGS='-DHello')
Program('mya','a.o')
```

Run scons again. Nothing is done:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

This is quite weird to me. When I used make or msbuild systems, whenever there's argumenet change in project configuration file, there'll be a rebuild. This is a default rule.

But seems scons's rule is different, is this by design? Only when source file change will trigger rebuild? If this is the design, I think there's a flaw that when compilation/linker option changes, target file should be different and thus, should trigger rebuild, right?

Is my understanding incorrect, or there's some special points in scons that I still need to know about?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aside: no `make` that I've ever used had this feature. In fact, this feature is one of the advantages of SCons over make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refering directly to your last paragraph, and based on your last three questions ([Using 'LIBS' in scons 'Program' command failed to find static library, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831985/using-libs-in-scons-program-command-failed-to-find-static-library-why) and [When changing the comment of a .c file, scons still re-compile it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832072/when-changing-the-comment-of-a-c-file-scons-still-re-compile-it) and this one) and the depth of them, yes there seem to be a lot of things that you don't know about SCons.

So please take the next steps in reading its [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) and the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html). You might also want to step your tone down a bit and instead of questioning its design or claiming that there seems to be a "flaw" doing your homework (see also [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)).

When you are calling a "`scons -c`" followed by a "`scons`" you should see that the "`-DHello`" doesn't appear in the command-line, even though "`a.o`" gets rebuilt. The variable `$CCFLAGS` isn't used to compile assembler files, but `$ASFLAGS` is...and when setting it instead, you should indeed see a rebuild immediately, without editing the source file.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs are commentary, not rightly part of the answer. Yes, they are valid comments, but comments nevertheless. Please consider moving them out of your answer and into a comment.